# Signal Acquisition Game?

Tags: signal-analysis

I read from Wikipedia that signals obey the uncertainty principle. The product of the measured uncertainty in frequency times the measured uncertainty in time is greater than a constant. The localization of both frequency and time is not possible simultaneous.

Can two people play a signal game with signal acquisition? Player A sends a signal to player B. Player B listens to the signal. Player A stops transmitting the signal after a short period of time. Player B must calculate from the limited time signal what the frequency spectra is

Is this a real game in the world?

Comment: [offtop] I've seen many strange "games" in my life... For example students of mathematics were writing function on sheet of paper and each player was transforming it, unless someone says "I check", and then this person must calculate integral of a given function. If he can't then he loses and goes for Vodka ;) [/offtop] I don't really understand your rules though. If B receives signal, then he can calculate spectra only in one way - there is no other option. Duration and type of the signal dictates frequency response and resolution.

Comment: @jojek Good point. I think the rules would be something like: If the player A transmits too little of the signal in time, then player A looses acquired points from B. If player A allows the signal to be sent too long, player A increases the risk of player B identifying the frequency too precisely?

Comment: This really sounds interesting but I am not sure how it could be developed further on the main DSP.SE board. We have the tag "puzzle" for off track brainteaser type questions and the chat for more free-form discussion. Creating a game would be best in a forum-type interaction. Many aspects in telecommunications could be "game-ified" by the way. What you describe sounds closer to channel equalisation. A straightforward approach would be to [decode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_decoder) the message in the presence of noise.

Comment: You could call it a game, or you could call it Spectral Analysis, or a proposed communication protocol.  A rose is rose....   However, I'd like to see a cite and a quote of the application of the uncertainty principle as you have stated it, because there is no uncertainty like that.  A DFT is deterministic.  However, you can find something about narrowing pulses going through a FT and how that relates to the Daddy of all uncertainty principles, i.e. Heisenberg's.

Comment: @A_A Whoops, I just noticed this is a really old post.

Comment: @CedronDawg Indeed. Still an interesting idea though.